# Is $μ_\bar{X} = μ$ the same thing as saying the mean of the population is the same as the mean of the sample?

Tags: statistics

My e-textbook is telling me that, when finding a sample from a population using a normal probability distribution, $\mu_\bar{X}$ is roughly equal to $μ$. It then gives me a problem asking me to find the probability that the sample mean is $110$ given that the parent population's mean = $100$ and the standard deviation = $15$. I thought, "surely the probability is $0$, since the population and sample mean should roughly equal each other," but this is clearly not the correct thinking, as evidenced by the video in the textbook giving a completely reasonable explanation and solution of $2%$. I'm clearly missing some crucial information, or the textbook just worded the explanation and question strangely.

Comment: Check out Cross Validated (statistics branch of the StackExchange network) for the question.

Comment: @KingLogic As in repost this question over there? Just making sure.

Comment: You could, but I would recommend checking if this question or a similar question is asked there first before posting it.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of a sample is equal to the expected value of the population (assuming the latter exists). Using linearity of expectation:

$$\mu_{\bar{X}}=\mathbb E\left[\bar X\right]=\mathbb E\left[\frac1n \sum_1^n X_i\right] = \frac1n\mathbb E\left[ \sum_1^n X_i\right] = \frac1n \sum_1^n \mathbb E\left[X_i\right] = \frac1n \sum_1^n \mu = \frac1n n \mu = \mu$$

This is exact for the expectation of the sample mean.  What may be approximate is that the actually observed sample mean can be close to the population mean, as a consequence of the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), at least when the [standard error of the sample mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_the_mean) is small, often as the result of a large enough sample.

Comment: It turns out that I was only confused because I misread the textbook page. It did not occur to me that $μ_\bar{X} = μ$ was saying that $μ_\bar{X} is the mean of all possible sample means combined, therefore being equal to that of the population. My misconception was that I miss the phrase "mean of the means," therefore thinking that the "sample mean" being different from the population mean was impossible.

Comment: (Second comment due to message length)
Also, I'm a freshman in college only taking my first statistics course, and that whole string was barely understandable for me. However, I appreciate the effort you put in to answering my blunder.